# How to change itemsControl stackpanel background color

Tags: c#, wpf, itemscontrol, stackpanel

Says I have a list of 10 items `someList`, I will show them on my page via `itemsControl` like below:

```
<ItemsControl DataContext="{Binding [someViewModel]}" 
              BorderBrush="Black" 
              ItemSource="{Binding someList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderThickness="1" Background="Green">
                <StackPanel MouseDown="{Binding Path=DataContext.someCommand,   
                                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" 
                                        Command Parameter="{Binding someID}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding something}">
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I do able to trigger `someCommand` method and I do able to pass in `someID` as input parameter. Now I'm wondering how to update the stackPanel background color, making it looks like "selected". Meaning now all item will have a green background, when I click on one of the stackpanel, that stackpanel should change background to red and change others back to green

Comment: Why not change `ItemTemplate` to be `RadioButton` in one group and style that for when it's checked/unchecked or better yet use `ListBox` with single selection and style that?

Comment: Or use ListView and dataTemplate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `ItemsControl` you can change `ItemTemplate` to `RadioButton` with custom `ControlTemplate` that will include `Border` which `Background` would change to *Red* when `IsChecked == true`:

```
<ItemsControl DataContext="{Binding [someViewModel]}" BorderBrush="Black" ItemSource="{Binding someList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <RadioButton Content="{Binding something}" GroupName="radioGroup">
                <RadioButton.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                        <Border Background="Green" x:Name="PART_Border">
                            <ContentPresenter/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="PART_Border" Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </RadioButton.Template>
            </RadioButton>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

However I don't see a reason why you cannot use `ListBox` with `SelectionMode=Single` (default value) and change `Template` of `ListBoxItem`:

```
<ListBox DataContext="{Binding [someViewModel]}" BorderBrush="Black" ItemSource="{Binding someList}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                        <Border Background="Green" x:Name="PART_Border">
                            <ContentPresenter/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="PART_Border" Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

or even do something like this, without changing `Template`:

```
<ListBox DataContext="{Binding [someViewModel]}" BorderBrush="Black" ItemSource="{Binding someList}">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Red"/>
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

In WPF it's generally much easier to pick a control that has functionality that you need and style it to look like you want then do this the other way round

Answer (score 0):

why not do something like this

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Border BorderThickness="1" Background="Green" x:Name="MyBorder">
        <StackPanel MouseDown="{Binding Path=DataContext.someCommand,   
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" 
            Command Parameter="{Binding someID}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding something}">
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected}" Value="true">
                    <Setter TargetName="MyBorder" Property="Background" Value="Black" />
            </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Your way doesn't work. I guess it's because `MyBorder` is not unique?

Comment: it doesnt work that way - myborder is unique within the scope of the datatemplate (which is an encapsulation boundary) so it will work as I've shown

Comment: you need an IsSelected' property on the data item you've bound to (like textblock is binding to the 'something' property. Your command in your viewmodel needs to set the 'IsSelected' on the correct data item.